# Delete powerpoint presentation if it exists

Tags: matlab, powerpoint

I'm trying to do something like this, here is my code:

```
% Start an ActiveX session with PowerPoint:
ppt = actxserver('PowerPoint.Application');

% If Powerpoint with this title exists
if exist(pptTitle,'file');
  % Delete presentation:
  invoke(ppt.Presentations,'Delete',pptTitle);
end
```

But Matlab doesn't recognize that command. Does anyone know how to delete a Powerpoint presentation from Matlab?

And as a secondary question, is there a command in Matlab to close the powerpoint application if it is open?

Comment: ***1***. `if exist(pptTitle,'file');` You have a semi-colon at then end of line. ***2***. I don't know much about Matlab and PowerPoint but where are you checking? It seems to me that you are checking if the file exists on disk and then try to delete it on the ActiveX session. ***3***. Which of those commands do Matlab not recognise?

Comment: Your question does not reflect your accepted answer. You question seems to indicate that you are trying to delete a Powerpoint presentation using an ActiveX session but your accepted answer deletes it from disk.

Comment: I simply asked how to delete a powerpoint presentation with a matlab command. It was my error to try to do it through an activex session

Comment: You should update your question then so that future readers can understand the question and the answer. It is confusing at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check is the file exist and delete it:

```
  if exist(fileName, 'file')==2
      delete(fileName);
  end
```